# Работа с СОМ-портом - Устройство не возвращает данные

Tags: c#, com-порт

Делаю сейчас модуль для общения через СОМ-порт для серии девайсов, используя протокол, предоставленный производителем.

Для одной марки - все работает превосходно, но для другой серии (но той же марки!) почему-то чтение каких-либо значений - т.е. фактически получение ответа от аппарата - не происходит - ничего возвращается, хотя для обоих аппаратов описан один и тот же протокол общения.

Эта картина не наблюдается при дебаге модуля - во время отладки модуля все работает на ура - аппарат возвращает все запрашиваемые значения.

Обращение к производителю ничего не дало.

Может кто-то сталкивался с таким феноменом? Что посоветуйте?

Comment: Ну тут всё понятно. Можно принимать решение -- в морг

Comment: Протокол Modbus?
Работаете через "родной" COM или COM --> USB?

Comment: Оказывается, что даже такой вопрос можно понять... Я-то думал, что ТС его хорошо зашифровал

Comment: Просто я решил(решаю?)подобную проблему. Сам не ожидал что COM еще не умер. Ряд современных(!) автономных уст-в для смены настроек  и снятия показаний используют только его. Кстати, поэтому (и не только) рынок GPRS-модемов существует.

Comment: @Oleg53
Стандартный СОМ порт... 
Нашел решение? Можешь поделится?

@alexlz
Зря вы так...

Comment: @dreadangel что зря? Выражаю недовольство шифрованными вопросами? Так тут зачастую от вопрошающих без третьей степени воздействия сути проблемы не добъёшься

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не зря спросил о протоколе. Modbus, в частности:

1. Определяет время ожидания ответа. Зависит от длины и скорости.
2. При новом/повторном запросе прекращает обработку предыдущего и обрабатывает текущий.

Нельзя не учитывать, что само уст-во не только ждет запроса, но и работает тоже. Поэтому пропуск запроса явление нормальное. Одно из требований моего заказчика - Delphi, не C#...

Сам протокол со стороны PC:

1. Определить количество повторных запросов при не ответе. (мне достаточно 3).
2. Перед запросом определить время ожидания ответа.
3. Отправить запрос.
4. При отсутствии ответа отправить запрос до п.1 раз.
5. Следующий запрос - п.2-3 и при необходимости п.4.

И еще. Лучше работать по событиям.

До вечера меня не будет.